# javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker:... already connected

Tags: java, activemq-classic

We have two brokers set up. it can work fine two or three days. Suddenly, every broker will try to create connection to each other, but because 
There are already has connected to each other, so it will throw a `javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException`.The brokers will retry after 6 second, and the same exception will happened.

**activemq.log**

> 1:02:54,925 | INFO  | Establishing network connection from vm://MQServer1?async=false to tcp://MQServer-2:61618 | org.apache.activemq.network.DiscoveryNetworkConnector | Notifier-MulticastDiscoveryAgent-listener:DiscoveryNetworkConnector:NC:BrokerService[MQServer1]
>   1:02:55,097 | WARN  | Failed to add Connection MQServer1->MQServer2-123456-123456788990-123:1 due to javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: MQServer1 - Client: NC_MQServer2_inbound_MQServer1 already connected from vm://MQServer1#2 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | triggerStartAsyncNetworkBridgeCreation: remoteBroker=tcp://MQServer-2/190.100.100.11:61618@56430, localBroker= vm://MQServer1#4
>   1:02:55,097 | INFO  | Network connection between vm://MQServer1#4 and tcp://MQServer-2/190.100.100.11:61618@56430 shutdown due to a local error: javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: MQServer1 - Client: NC_MQServer2_inbound_MQServer1 already connected from vm://MQServer1#2 | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | triggerStartAsyncNetworkBridgeCreation: remoteBroker=tcp://MQServer-2/190.100.100.11:61618@56430, localBroker= vm://MQServer1#4
>   1:02:55,144 | INFO  | MQServer1 bridge to MQServer2 stopped | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[MQServer1] Task-2043

**wrapper.log**

> INFO   | jvm 1    | 1:02:55 |  INFO | Establishing network connection from vm://MQServer1?async=false to tcp://MQServer-2:61618
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 1:02:55 |  WARN | Failed to add Connection MQServer1->MQServer2-123456-123456788990-123:1 due to javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: MQServer1 - Client: NC_MQServer2_inbound_MQServer1 already connected from vm://MQServer1#2
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 1:02:55 |  INFO | Network connection between vm://MQServer1#4 and tcp://MQServer-2/190.100.100.11:61618@56430 shutdown due to a local error: javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: MQServer1 - Client: NC_MQServer2_inbound_MQServer1 already connected from vm://MQServer1#2
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | 1:02:55 |  INFO | MQServer1 bridge to MQServer2 stopped

Comment: Did you resolve this error? I am experiencing the exact same behaviour with ActiveMQ 5.10.2.

Comment: I saw you posted the problem in several other forums and even the activemq JIRA. Did you hear anything regarding the impact of the problem (is it even a real problem?) or some clue as what causes the problem?

Posting your other links here for reference:
 - https://www.mail-archive.com/users@activemq.apache.org/msg34953.html
 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-6075